# CUDA from Ubuntu PPA: Compiling first CUDA program

Tags: c, cuda

I installed [CUDA from an Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aaron-haviland/+archive/cuda-4.0).  Now I want to test the installation.

I grabbed a [small sample program from another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285185/easiest-way-to-test-for-existence-of-cuda-capable-gpu-from-cmake/2285228#2285228).  It imports cuda.h and cuda_runtime.h.  Does this mean I need to use nvcc to compile the program or should I use gcc?

When I try to compile I get the errors below.  How do I tell the compiler where to find the necessary libraries?  Also, how do I find those libraries myself?  I'm not sure where the PPA installation put them or the names of the libraries I should be looking for.

```
detect_cuda.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `cudaGetDeviceCount'
detect_cuda.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `cudaGetLastError'
detect_cuda.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
detect_cuda.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `cudaGetDeviceProperties'
```

Comment: add `-lcudart` to linker/compiler

Comment: But why this is needed? If I search `nvcc -h` for `lcudart` or `cudart` i find nothing. It looks like linking cuda runtime but why this is even needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding -lcudart worked as Anycom suggested in the comments.

```
nvcc -lcudart detect_cuda.cu
```