# How can I run nvcc in cmake's try_run?

Tags: cuda, cmake, nvcc

I try to set compute capability flag of `nvcc` in stage of cmake by compiling and running simple test:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    cudaDeviceProp dP;
    if(cudaSuccess != cudaGetDeviceProperties(&dP, 0)) return 0;
    printf("-arch=sm_%d%d\n", dP.major, dP.minor);
    return 0;
}
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285185/easiest-way-to-test-for-existence-of-cuda-capable-gpu-from-cmake) how to do it, but `try_run` let me compile targets only by gcc. If I add `cuda_compile`, I don't get a binary file too.

How can I compile `.cu`-file at stage of `cmake` and run it by `execute_process` to set right compile flags?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know how to do it right, so I did simple.
In beginning of my `CUDA_FOUND` section I add:

```
if(CUDA_FOUND)
    set(TEST ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test)
    set(TESTSRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/capability.cu)
    execute_process(COMMAND nvcc -lcuda ${TESTSRC} -o ${TEST})
    execute_process(COMMAND ${TEST} OUTPUT_VARIABLE CUDA_ARCH)
    message("Cuda architecture:  ${CUDA_ARCH}")
    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS --use_fast_math ${CUDA_ARCH})
```

This simply compiles my test source and run in filling `CUDA_ARCH` variable.