# Is there a way to detect if a system has GPU or CPU in R for Windows, Linux and Mac?

Tags: r, linux, windows, operating-system, gpu

I'm curious about this. Is there a way to know if a system has GPU or just a graphical chip with R? It would be great to know this for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285185/easiest-way-to-test-for-existence-of-cuda-capable-gpu-from-cmake